# Writing a Jolt transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I am trying to write a Jolt Transformation for the below input json.

```json
{
  "templateLanguage": "FREEMARKER",
  "outputFormat": "JSON",
  "templateName": "MPX",
  "data": {
    "DSID": "36455-001",
    "media": {
      "subtitle": [
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_caption_5005141918_202401030424.vtt",
          "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
          "materialSubType": "Feature",
          "locale": "es-419"
        }
      ],
      "caption": [
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_CCAP_T3092_Closed_Caption_SCC_2398_engCC_5005136914_202401030425.scc",
          "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
          "materialSubType": "Feature",
          "locale": "en-US"
        }
      ],
      "audio": [
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_AOUTPUT_A4970_Audio_BWF_2398_5_1_Interleaved_engAU_5005143352.wav",
          "channels": "6",
          "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
          "materialSubType": "Feature",
          "locale": "en-US",
          "type": "5.1 Surround"
        },
        {
          "dvs": true,
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_AOUTPUT_A4964_Audio_BWF_2398_2_0_Interleaved_engAU_5005143913.wav",
          "channels": "2",
          "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
          "materialSubType": "Feature",
          "locale": "en-US",
          "type": "2.0 Stereo (L/R)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Output JSON should look like this:

```json
{
  "videos": [
    {
      "textTracks": [
        {
          "techSpec": {
            "type": "subtitle",
            "locale": "es-419",
            "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118"
          },
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_caption_5005141918_202401030424.vtt"
        },
        {
          "techSpec": {
            "type": "caption",
            "locale": "es-US",
            "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118"
          },
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_CCAP_T3092_Closed_Caption_SCC_2398_engCC_5005136914_202401030425.scc"
        }
      ],
      "audios": [
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_AOUTPUT_A4970_Audio_BWF_2398_5_1_Interleaved_engAU_5005143352.wav",
          "techSpec": {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
            "materialSubType": "Feature",
            "type": "5.1 Surround"
          }
        },
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_AOUTPUT_A4964_Audio_BWF_2398_2_0_Interleaved_engAU_5005143913.wav",
          "techSpec": {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "dvs": true,
            "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118",
            "materialSubType": "Feature",
            "type": "2.0 Stereo (L/R)"
          }
        }
      ],
      "mediaMetadata": [
        {
          "fileName": "Tiger_s_Apprentice_The_36455_001_FTR_DOC_Document_Color_Spec_16x9LB_engPT_5005134061.xml",
          "techSpec": {
            "filePath": "ingest/viacom/paramountdvhdrsdr/8100132118"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with the below Jolt Spec but it is not working as expected.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "media": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "*": {
              "fileName": "images[&1].fileName",
              "filePath": "images[&1].techSpec.filePath"
            }
          },
          "subtitle": {
            "*": {
              "fileName": "textTracks[&1].fileName",
              "#subtitle": "textTracks[&1].techSpec.type",
              "locale": "textTracks[&1].techSpec.locale",
              "filePath": "textTracks[&1].techSpec.filePath"
            }
          },
          "caption": {
            "*": {
              "fileName": "textTracks[&2].fileName",
              "#caption": "textTracks[&2].techSpec.type",
              "locale": "textTracks[&2].techSpec.locale",
              "filePath": "textTracks[&2].techSpec.filePath"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried changes my Jolt spec but it the videos as outer array and textTracks with both Subtitle and caption as different object is not working as expected.

Comment: Hi. There no object named `mediaMetadata`, you might include that as well with respect to the model I've already presented within the answer if that exists within your original output.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following **shift** transformations :

```json
[ // accumulate subtitle and caption objects into the common object
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "media": {
          "subtitle|caption": { // make the node common by prefixing them as "sc"
            "*": {
              "fileName": "sc.textTracks.&",
              "$1": "sc.textTracks.techSpec[&1].type",
              "locale|filePath": "sc.textTracks.techSpec[&1].&"
            }
          },
          "audio": {
            "*": {
              "fileName": "&2s[&1].&", // prefix sub-elements by audios through 
                                       // use of &2 and the letter s
              "locale|filePath|*ype": "&2s[&1].techSpec.&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sc": { // loop through all sc in order to separate the components of the
             //  arrays into different objects respectively by the index values 
             // of those arrays such as 0,1..
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "@": "videos[0].&5.&4.[&1].&2"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "videos[0].&"
    }
  }
]
```